# How do I add a custom hide/close link to a modal box displayed using lightbox2?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/. It has a "X" button in its corner that closes the modal box. I want to add another close link in the window (a text link).

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeLightboxWindow('lightboxId')">Close</a>
```

How do I implement closeLightboxWindow()? :)

Answer (score 0):

Link:

```
<a class="closeLightbox2" href="javascript:none;">Close</a>
```

Find in lightbox.js string:

```
$lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function(e) {
```

Add like that your class

```
$lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close, .closeLightbox2').on('click', function(e) {
```

That's all, don't forget clear browser cache

Comment: Thanks luther. Do you think I could do it without editing lightbox.js? :) *I am using the Lighbox Pop Wordpress plugin and I would like to embed all code I need in the HTML window in the WSWIG editor it provides :)*

Comment: Yes you can. Use this function: `function closeLightboxWindow() {Lightbox.end();};`